# How to construct tumor phylogenetic tree?

Tags: bioinformatics, cancer, dna-sequencing, phylogenetics

I would like to know if anyone has tried any software that constructs tumor evolution trees where the trunks represent the common mutations and the private alterations are noted on each branch. I can do it manually but the sample size is too big (nearly 100 patients). Here's a good example of what I'm after here on Figure4 http://www.nature.com/nm/journal/v21/n7/full/nm.3886.html

Any additional computational model suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I do not know if this is exactly what you are looking for. The ETE toolkit for python is possibly worth a look.